# How can I choose a motor for my project?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors

I'm working in a project that consists of something similar to a motorized skate. I know how to do it, but I don't know what motor to use. I need that the skate to be able to move 90 Kg to 20 Kph (12 miles per hour) or more if it's possible. I also need the motor as cheap as possible.

I have read things about motors but we can say that I don't know anything about them.

What kind of motor and what facts do I need? What transmission ratio should I use between the motor and the wheels? What size and type of wheels? Any special type of transmission?

I know the basic mechanics, but I don't know what motor should I use, my requirements are:

- Move 90 Kg to 20 Kph (if the motor for that is very expensive only 15 kph)
- I don't mind the acceleration
- I think that it should work with battery (I'm not sure)
- The skate is thought for city, but may have to go up small slopes
- As cheaper as possible

I don't have the budget to buy numerous motors and try them all, so I need to be sure that it will work before I purchase one.

Comment: Your English is fine, but this question is very broad right now. Maybe you could restate it to just start with picking the motor, then do more questions for the other details. For that, it would be helpful to know the following: Does the skate need to go up or down hills? What kind of power source are you expecting? (Battery, plugs in to AC power, compressed air, etc.) Also how fast does it need to accelerate (like a skateboard, or fast like a car or bicycle?)

Comment: Welcome to Engineering.SE. As Ethan48 said, there are too many questions in there. Each one could be a separate topic.

Comment: As others have politely hinted, your question seems to be asking us to do half your project for you. Try something; if it doesn't work, and you can't figure out why, then you have a problem we can help you solve. "I haven't tried anything yet" is a problem that *only you can solve*.

Comment: I might add that, although you say 'I know how to do it', both the specifications (which are, well, vague) and the follow-up questions indicate that you don't *really* know how to do it. I think that reading up on basic mechanics might help you a lot!

Comment: What country are you in? Used cordless electric drills MAY BE cheap and MAY provide enough power for what you need. Do not take my word for this !!! Investigate them yourself.